# How to use an object which was given from an enum in a switch statement?

Tags: swift

How can I use an object which was given from an enum in a switch statement?

```
enum objects {
    case classOne(classOne)
    case classTwo(classTwo)
}

func loadClass(load: objects) {
    switch load {
    case .classOne(_):
        load.something //doesn't work
    case .classTwo(_):
        classTwo.something //doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at documentation? https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare names to bind the associated properties to instead of using `_`.

```
class ClassOne {
    func something() {
        print("Hello, world")
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    func something2() {
        print("Hello, world (2)")
    }
}

enum Objects {
    case classOne(ClassOne)
    case classTwo(ClassTwo)
}

func loadClass(load: Objects) {
    switch load {
    case .classOne(let classOne): //can also be written: case let .classOne(classOne):
        classOne.something()
    case .classTwo(let classTwo):
        classTwo.something2()
    }
}
```

Note how I've also used the standard Swift naming convention of starting type names with capital letters and property/variable/member names with lowercase letters.